# Batch file won't kill process and close console window

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-7

Batch is a mystery to me. Here is the situation. I used a mouse macro program to create a .exe that automatically clicks on my screen. I want to automate this by adding it to my task scheduler. Here is the code that the program created:

```
@echo off
REM ************ Built by MiniMouseMacro.exe **********
cls
mode con lines=11 cols=115
title=Mini Mouse Macro - Turnssoft.com
color 0A
echo * Mini Mouse Macro *
echo   - "C:\Users\John Doe\Desktop\MiniMouseMacro.exe" /m "C:\Users\John Doe\Desktop\TestKlik.mmmacro"
echo   - Running C:\Users\John Doe\Desktop\TestKlik.mmmacro...
"C:\Users\John Doe\Desktop\MiniMouseMacro.exe" /m "C:\Users\John Doe\Desktop\TestKlik.mmmacro"
```

It opens the Macro program, loads the macro file (.mmmacro) and executes. This works. However, it keeps the console window open + it keeps the Macro program open (the mouse click opens a new program, might the console window lose focus or something?). I tried to fix this by adding this to the script:

```
echo   - killing process
taskkill /im "MiniMouseMacro.exe" /f
end
```

But nothing happens. How can I make this script work and also maybe make it look cleaner (I dont need all the text output).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the program, the cmd will wait for the program to finish before it continues. To change this use the `start` command when starting the mouse program.

```
cd "C:\Users\John Doe\Desktop\"
start "" "MiniMouseMacro.exe /m TestKlik.mmmacro"
```

Which will allow you to follow it with a `taskkill`

Comment: add a `timeout -t 2` to give the exe a chance to do, what it should do before you kill it.

Comment: This worked, thank you. Also the timeout is a very welcome addition.